# How to refresh cache mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Was going through the cache mediator in ESB and planning to use it. As I understood,cache mediator calls the end point if the request is not cached and returns the same response for subsequent requests. In my case if the end point service is updated to return different out put then how does ESB knows that the end point result is updated and need to refresh the cache in ESB. In nutshell I would like to know is there any way to invalidate cache in WSO2 ESB. Not seeing anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

The ESB cache implementation does not contain direct support for cache synchronization and cache invalidation.  You need to build a service endpoint that will receive data modification messages and either invalidate or update the cache entry.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current caching implementation, it generates a hash for the request and get the cached response for the particular hash and the cached response is refreshed after the current caching time expires